# Using sed to modify line, passing a password hash variable

Tags: hash, sed

I am passing a user inputted password to a hashing script for an Elasticsearch plugin, from which the output is being passed to sed to modify a static auth file. Sometimes the script fails, my guess is due to the hashed output. Any suggestions on the code to improve this and prevent it from failing occasionally? Note that the SED commands delete the original hashed password line then insert the new one.

```
stty -echo
printf "Please enter a password for the admin user: "
read password
stty echo
printf "\n"
chmod +x /usr/share/elasticsearch/plugins/search-guard-5/tools/hash.sh
passwordhash=$(/usr/share/elasticsearch/plugins/search-guard-5/tools/hash.sh -p $password)
sed -i '4d' /usr/share/elasticsearch/plugins/search-guard-5/sgconfig/sg_internal_users.yml
sed -i "3 a\  \hash: $passwordhash" /usr/share/elasticsearch/plugins/search-guard-5/sgconfig/sg_internal_users.yml
```

Comment: _How_ does the script fail occasionally? Please update your question directly.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tested this script for values of password that contain spaces and asterisks? If not, I recommend you put together a simplistic test suite to help you debug your code. You'll probably need to quote your use of $password on line 7

Answer (score 0):

Since you are merely replacing line 4 of the file, I would strongly recommend using sed very differently.  I would do:

```
trap 'rm $tmp' 0
tmp=$(mktemp)
input=/usr/share/elasticsearch/plugins/search-guard-5/sgconfig/sg_internal_users.yml
sed 3q "$input" > $tmp
echo "  \hash: $passwordhash" >> $tmp
sed 1,4d "$input" >> $tmp
# Some command here to validate $tmp
mv $tmp $input
```

Using `sed -i` with a script that is known to fail intermittently is a disaster waiting to happen.  (Or, indeed, one that has already happened!)

Comment: Thank you, I actually just ended up escaping all special characters like this, but will attempt this next time! passwordhash=$(/usr/share/elasticsearch/plugins/search-guard-5/tools/hash.sh -p $password)
passwordhash=$(sed -e 's/[]\/$*.^|[]/\\&/g' <<< "$passwordhash")